# Operator < cannot be applied to types Number and boolean

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have three numbers and I am trying to compare if one of them includes in other 2.

```
  let myMonthly = this.profile.expectedpayhourlystart + 
  this.profile.expectedpayhourlyend;
  myMonthly = ((((myMonthly/2)*8)*5)*4);
  let jobStart = item.monthlyPrice - 200;
  let jobEnd = item.monthlyPrice + 200;

  if( jobEnd < myMonthly < jobStart ){ <-- 'Operator < cannot be applied to boolean or number'

  }
```

Why I am getting this error ? What should I change ?

Comment: `if (jobEnd < myMonthly && myMonthly < jobStart)`

Comment: Yep this helped. Will wait for the explanation why this works and that didn't.

Comment: The `<` operator is binary, has two operands, the problem is that the expression is parsed as: `(jobEnd < myMonthly) < jobStart`, the first operand `(jobEnd < myMonthly)` results in a boolean value, and the subsequent operator gets a boolean and a number. Check the [AST](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/0fb4ba4b7d2573dfcfc2e77b381d7eda/16afc30310b053c9f347c6d7778197ed90a4dc5e)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
jobEnd < myMonthly
```

will evaluate to true or false.
So if you write:

```
if( jobEnd < myMonthly < jobStart)
```

it essentially tries to evaluate

```
if( true < jobStart )
```

which is **applying a < operator to boolean** because jobStart is a number.

You need to write it like this:

```
if( jobEnd < myMonthly && myMonthly < jobStart )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stack the < operator like that it will evaluate `jobEnd < myMonthly` which results in a boolean and compare the result to `jobStart` which is a number. Use `&&` like

```
if (jobEnd < myMonthly &&  myMonthly < jobStart)
```